# What is use of Service Endpoint given in Solution in MS Dynamics 365?

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365, dynamics-crm-365

There is a "Service Endpoint" tab in Solution. Can anybody please suggest what is use of it?

Actually, I have my own RESTful API which is hosted on azure. This API uses to transfer data operation from MS Dynamics to Mobile and visa versa. I want to add that API into solution(same as Sugar CRM and Salesforce CRM).

Is it possible to add my own service endpoint(using DLL of Visual Studio Project)? If not possible, can anybody please suggest what is use of "Service Endpoint" in my solution?

Please guide.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When some event happens on any entity record in CRM platform, we can intercept the event execution pipeline using plugin or workflow & execute our custom business logic to achieve what we need. This needs to be registered on certain messages along with stage & execution mode, this works only on CRM platform context.

What if we need that power outside CRM platform context like in Azure, that too with everything available in Plugin execution context like Entity attributes, Image, etc in Azure Event hub through Service bus endpoints.

[image]

[Reference](https://crmfortress.com/2016/05/26/dynamics-crm-azure-integration-part-2-create-dynamics-crm-service-endpoint/) - Everything is still valid except Azure ACS related config in this old post. Azure ACS is replaced with Shared Access Signature (SAS) later.

The Service endpoint can be assumed similar to an assembly with a plugin, against what we can register a plugin step to trigger & execute.

[Read more](https://colinvermander.com/2016/09/18/using-the-azure-service-bus-with-dynamics-crm-2016-spring-update/)

That’s why similar to Plugin assembly & SDK processing steps in solution you are seeing service endpoint.

Comment: Okay, thanks Arun. As far as I understand, I can get trigger(events) to my Azure based instance. So, this is like one way from MS Dynamics to Azure, right?. Also, Is there any possibility to add my web API project's DLL and access all the methods of that DLL project services using MS Dynamics Instance? Please suggest. This is possible in Sugar/Suite CRM and Salesforce.

Comment: @NanjiMange You can do ilmerge to merge the assemblies into single dll, but it was called out as unsupported.. http://develop1.net/public/post/2018/10/21/ILMergeNotSupported

Comment: @NanjiMange Dynamics don’t have option like this: https://www.greytrix.com/blogs/salesforce/2018/06/04/creating-an-endpoint-in-salesforce-and-using-rest-api-to-externally-access-it/ but you should research about Dynamics CRM virtual entity..

Comment: Hi @ArunVinoth, I could get a service endpoint working nicely. However, the messages arrived in the correspondent Azure Service Bus Queue didn't have a PostImage I specified. I added a PostImage when I registered the service endpoint.